# Symfony2 load settings from database

Tags: php, database, caching, symfony, settings

I have a db table (doctrine entity) that I use to store some editable settings for my app, like page title, maintenance mode (on/off), and some other things..

I can load the settings normally using the entity manager and repositories, but I think that's not the best solution...

My questions are:
- can I load the settings only once at some kernel event and then access them the same way I access any other setting saved in yml config files..

- how can I cache the database settings, so I would only do one DB query, and then in future page requests, it would use the cached values, instead of doing a DB query for each page request? (of course, everytime I change something in the settings, I would need to purge that cache, so the new settings could take effect)

Answer (score 2):

[LiipDoctrineCacheBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipDoctrineCacheBundle) provides a service wrapper around Doctrine's common Cache ([documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html)) that allows you to use several cache drivers like filesystem, apc, memcache, ...

I would recommend loading your generic container-parameters/settings (like maintainance mode,...) from database in a [bundle-extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class) or a [compiler-pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

route-specific settings (like page title, ...) could be loaded in a [kernel event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types). You can find a list of kernel events [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.html).

update/invalidate their cache using a doctrine postUpdate/postPersist/postRemove [listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).